# 3d Cylinder Bar Chart with Jfreechart

Tags: java

I need to make 3d Cylinder Bar Chart with Jfreechart as shown in the picture on link: http://www.jzy3d.org/gallery/web/demo-histogram.png . I have problems on two lines of code: `chart.getAxeLayout().setMainColor(Color.WHITE);` and `chart.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);`, both in the main method. Does anyone know what the problem is here?

Thanks in advance

```
import java.awt.Color;

import org.jzy3d.chart.Chart;
import org.jzy3d.chart.ChartLauncher;
import org.jzy3d.colors.ColorMapper;
import org.jzy3d.colors.colormaps.ColorMapRainbow;
import org.jzy3d.maths.Coord3d;
import org.jzy3d.plot3d.primitives.MultiColorScatter;

public class chart 
{
    int size = 100000;
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    public void crtaj()
    {
        Coord3d[] points = new Coord3d[size];

        // Create scatter points
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
            x = (float)Math.random() - 0.5f;
            y = (float)Math.random() - 0.5f;
            z = (float)Math.random() - 0.5f;
            points[i] = new Coord3d(x, y, z);
        }       

        // Create a drawable scatter with a colormap
        MultiColorScatter scatter = new MultiColorScatter( points, new ColorMapper( new ColorMapRainbow(), -0.5f, 0.5f ) );

        // Create a chart and add scatter
        Chart chart = new Chart();
        chart.getAxeLayout();//.setMainColor(Color.WHITE);
        chart.getView();//.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        chart.getScene().add(scatter);
        ChartLauncher.openChart(chart);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        /*chart proba = new chart();
        proba.crtaj();*/

        int size = 100000;
        float x;
        float y;
        float z;
        Coord3d[] points = new Coord3d[size];

        // Create scatter points
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
            x = (float)Math.random() - 0.5f;
            y = (float)Math.random() - 0.5f;
            z = (float)Math.random() - 0.5f;
            points[i] = new Coord3d(x, y, z);
        }       

        // Create a drawable scatter with a colormap
        MultiColorScatter scatter = new MultiColorScatter( points, new ColorMapper( new ColorMapRainbow(), -0.5f, 0.5f ) );

        Chart chart = new Chart();
        chart.getAxeLayout().setMainColor(Color.WHITE);
        chart.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        chart.getScene().add(scatter);
        ChartLauncher.openChart(chart);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you describe what your problem with those two lines of code is?

Comment: And this is Exception:   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 The method setMainColor(Color) in the type IAxeLayout is not applicable for the arguments (Color)
 The method setBackgroundColor(Color) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (Color)

Comment: Double-check that the fully qualified class name of the `Color` you're attempting to pass into the method matches the fully-qualified class name of the `Color` the method is expecting

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have imported `java.awt.Color`.
You need to import `org.jzy3d.colors.Color` instead of `java.awt.Color`.
Remove `java.awt.Color` import and add the import statement as below:

```
import org.jzy3d.colors.Color;
```

It is going to work.